# RxJava execution in ListenableWorker

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2, android-workmanager

I'm using `ListenableWorker` to apply some editing on my media and then create a post at the server. Everything is working good but there is a special case then when `api call` is sent to server and user kills the application before returning of response from server then though Post is created at server but post is not deleted from local database because the response was not received. Which causes the Worker to start again to retry uploading. How can i achieve the goal that even if the application gets closed but if api call is made then response should be received for that. I could have used Worker instead of `ListenableWorker` but that doesn't fulfill my needs. Can changing the Scheduler thread help, what is the right choice? Following is the code:

```
mCompositeDisposable.add(getDataManager().getApiHelper().createPostApiCall(token, input)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe(response -> {
                getDataManager().getDbHelper().deleteUploadPostById(postUpload.postLocalId);
                callback.onResponse(Result.success());
            }}, throwable -> { 
        callback.onFailure(getResult());
    }));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "user kills app"? Did you mean process "force stop" or just clearing the app from the recent app screen? Clearing from the "recent app" does mean force stopping the process in some devices. Also, is `.deleteUploadPostById()` synchronous?

Comment: Yes, i mean that is user closes the app. delete method is synchronous it just deletes entry from local db